# Rudin example 1.1 alternative choices of q

Tags: real-analysis

I apologize if this question is asked to death but I have specific doubt that I cannot answer. In Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis example 1.1, Rudin claims that given a rational number $p$ that satisfies $p^2<2$, there exists $q$ such that $p<q$ and $q^2<2$. His choice for $q$ that satisfies this criterion is

$$q=\frac{2p+2}{p+2}$$

I am wondering whether there are other possible choices of $q$ that satisfy the criterion. I thought of another $q$ and I am not sure if it works.

Since $p^2<2$, we have $2-p^2>0$. We could choose $q=p+\frac{2-p^2}{2}=\frac{2p-p^2+2}{2}$. Or more generally, one can choose $q=\frac{2p-p^2+2}{n}$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\ge2$. Will that choice of $q$ work? It makes me wonder if $p$ part in the denominator from Rudin's choice is really necessary.

Comment: Have you calculated $q^2$?

Comment: Very little in Rudin's proof (or similar proofs of similar results) is "really necessary."  His choices are the result of balancing a subjective view of the "simplicity" of a formula for q against a subjective view of the "simplicity" of proving (using only the ordered field axioms and the definition of q) that q has the desired property. It is not surprising that other people would make different choices. Perhaps unfortunately, analysis is full of arguments where a proof straight from the definitions may involve making a number of choices that are not forced or "necessary" in any strict sense

Comment: I always liked $q=(p+1/n)$ for some large $n.$

Comment: "I am wondering whether there are other possible choices of q that satisfy the criterion."  There are an infinite number of other possible choices . "Will that choice of q work?" It will if $q^2 < 2$.  Is it?  $(p+\frac{2-p^2}{2})^2 = p^2 +(2-p^2) + \frac {(2-p^2)^2}4 = 2 + \frac {(2-p^2)^2}4 > 2$.  So no, it fails.   I think you are getting at why Rudin picke it but you sort of need a $q=p+h$ so $p^2 +2ph + h^2$ is such that $2ph+h^2 < 2-p^2$.  Rudin mucked about and got his.  You can easily muck around and get something else.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take $q = \frac{2p - p^2 + 2}{n}$ for any integer $n \geq 2$. For $n=2$ and $p = 1$, you have
$$
q^2 = \frac{9}{4} > 2,
$$
and for $n \geq 3$ and $p = 1$, you have
$$
q = \frac{3}{n} \leq 1 = p.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your alternative works for some values of n, as long as it is both rational and $n > 2 \sqrt{2}$.

@terran is right for the first part of $n = 2$ not working, but I think wrong for the second part with a higher $n$.  For example, with $n = 3$ and $p = 1$ you get $q = \frac{4}{3}$, which is larger than $p$ but less than $\sqrt{2}$.
This is because $p = p - \frac{p^2 - 2}{n} = \frac{np - p^2 + 2}{n}$ and not $\frac{2p - p^2 + 2}{n}$.

It makes intuitive sense that $q$ stays larger than $p$ because $p^2 - 2$ is always negative and the denominator seeks to reduce the distance.  It's less intuitive whether or not a $p$ very close to $\sqrt{2}$ is going to produce a 'jump' large enough to push $q$ beyond $\sqrt{2}$ for a given denominator.  You can probably think about $a^2 + b^2 \lt (a + b)^2$ for positive $a$ and $b$ (with $p$ as $a$ and $\frac{2 - p^2}{n}$ as $b^2$) to prove or convince yourself of that.

Here is a [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/3d/43b591d37a) I made that lets you see the space in 3d, with the x-axis as $p$ and the y-axis as the denominator as a function of $p$.  The red lines are independent of $x$ and show the $n = 2$ and $n = 4$ cases.  You can see that the red surface, where the z-axis represents is $q$ stays above x = z (so $q > p$), and most of it stays below $\sqrt{2}$.

[image]

Incidentally, I don't know why the boundary is at $2\sqrt{2}$, I just observed it, but it probably would be an interesting exercise to find out why if I had more time.